# Why do I get 400 Status code for Rest API delete call

Tags: java, rest, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a Rest API call using mockito. Many times I tried executing the below test case it fails with the following status code:400

I have checked the URI, the URI passed is also fine but I would like to know where I am missing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/todo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Response> removeToDoById(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam((value = "reason") String reason) ) throws ToDoException{
    logger.info("ToDo id to remove " + id);
    ToDo toDo = toDoService.getToDoById(id);
    if (toDo == null || toDo.getId() <= 0){
        throw new ToDoException("ToDo to delete doesn´t exist");
    }
    toDoService.removeToDo(toDo);
    return new ResponseEntity<Response>(new Response(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "ToDo has been deleted"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Below is the test call

```
@Test
public void verifyDeleteToDo() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/todo/4").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value(200))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value("ToDo has been deleted"))
    .andDo(print());
}
```

Comment: 400 error code is 'bad request', it means the syntax is invalid

Comment: that is what I am thinking, the syntax is also fine.. i just passed the URI as /todo/4 for /todo/{id}

Comment: Maybe you have configured exception mapping so that `ToDoException` is mapped to HTTP CODE 400? BTW, in your test method you do not mock `toDoService` so the call `toDoService.getToDoById(id)` will always return null.

Comment: I have done a little bit of debugging and found that error message **Required String parameter 'reason' is not present** , Where should I pass the request param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method requires additional parameter `reason` which you don't provide in request to **mockMvc** in your test method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/todo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Response> removeToDoById(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam((value = "reason") String reason) ) throws ToDoException{
```

Either give it to mockMvc

```
mockMvc.perform(delete("/todo/4")
                .param("reason", "bla-bla")
                // omitted
```

or mark it as "not required"

```
@RequestParam(required = false, value = "reason") String reason
```

Comment: I cannot change the code, its part of application, How can i git it to **mockMvc**